# macro expansion using flag variables at runtime

Tags: c

```
    if (a==5)
    {
    #define FLAG 1
    }

    #ifdef FLAG
    {
    // Execute this portion else not
    }
    #endif
```

I want to use this as flag variable and if the variable is defined(at runtime depending upon condition) then the piece if code in #ifdef shall be executed else not.

If this is not possible in c programming then please suggest me the best way to implement the same.
Which can help in faster execution of code. Also reduced compilation time

Comment: The preprocessor is compile-time, not runtime. As James McLaughlin suggested, you need a runtime variable.

Comment: @Dave moreover, it is PRE-compile time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `FLAG` is not variable, it is a preprocessor symbol.
2) The preprocessor is running from top to bottom defining the symbols (or undefining them) regardless of your *compilable* code logic (so of course it can't depend on it), before it is even compiled. So in your example the `#ifdef` will always work. 
3) To achieve the functionality you seem to want, just use a regular if/else statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool flag = false;

if (a == 5)
{
    flag = true;
}

if (flag)
{
    // [...]
}
```

Comment: That increases the binary size been built. that is the reason why i need some optimization. Here I am talking of a very large piece of code.

Comment: How do you want to optimize away a piece of code, when whether it is needed is determined at runtime?

Comment: @PKSA But you DO want the code in your program in case the `a` is not 5, right? Or it is constant?

Comment: If the condition as given in example if (a == 5) turns out to be true then that flag shall be used else not

Comment: @PKSA Do you understand how compiler and preprocessor work? Have you read my answer as well?

Comment: Yes i totally undesrtand how compiler works but thought people might come up with some better implementation jus by looking at the question being asked. 
any way thanks for taking your time and helping me to get to the conclusion.